# How can I access a text field located in a table view cell outside of the cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

After searching around, I couldn't find a solution that worked for me. I have a couple of text fields in a table cell. What I am trying to accomplish is changing those fields from hidden to visible with a leadingSwipe.

Code for `cellForRowAt`:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let newCategory = cell.viewWithTag(5) as! UITextField
    let newAmount = cell.viewWithTag(6) as! UITextField
    newCategory.isHidden = true
    newAmount.isHidden = true
    return cell
}
```

Code for leadingSwipe:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    let contextItem = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
        cell.newCategory.isHidden = false
        cell.newAmount.isHidden = false
        boolValue(false)
    }
    let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [contextItem])

    return swipeActions
}
```

I am receiving the error "Value of type 'UITableViewCell?' has no member 'newCategory'" and similar for the newAmount.

Answer (score 0):

Moving `let newCategory = cell.viewWithTag(5) as! UITextField` and `let newAmount = cell.viewWithTag(6) as! UITextField` into the leadingSwipe function did the job.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
   let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
   let newCategory = cell.viewWithTag(5) as! UITextField
   let newAmount = cell.viewWithTag(6) as! UITextField
   let contextItem = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
      newCategory.isHidden = false
      newAmount.isHidden = false
      boolValue(false)
}
let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [contextItem])

return swipeActions
}
```

Comment: BTW don't create tags use outlets

Comment: Use outlets in `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: No @Sh_Khan means, create new TableviewCell class and create outlets there.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! Got it figured out and working.